# Portable Extensible Metadata (PEM) and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

In a previous project, I used the ["Portable Extensible Metadata"](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e6467914-d48d-4075-8885-ce5a0dcb744d) tool. It was helpful in that it allowed me to store the label text and the tooltip text in the EMDX and show them in the WPF-UI. The feature to store the valuation is also nice, but I don´t need it urgently.

Now I use VS2013 and I can't install PEM anymore. How can I find a updated version of this extension? Where can I find the source code so that I can compile a custom-version for my project?

Comment: Fixed some grammar and link formatting

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a project which involves the same setup, that is, PEM using VS2013. 
Earlier when I was using VS2010, it gave me the option of product VS2010 only for this extension(pem.VSIX) to be installed to. Even now, when I have VS2013 installed on my machine, it gives the same option of installing this extension to VS2010 and not VS2013, as I tried uninstalling and re-installing this extension. Please refer to the screenshot.
Just to mention, the extension can be installed simply be double-clicking on it.

[image: VSIX Extension Installer image]

The following is what I did and it worked for me.

Look for PEM_VSIX2012 on the internet or just make changes to the VSIX for VS2010 that you have at your disposal. Open this archive using 7-Zip tool and you will find a bunch of files. Look for the file "extension.vsixmanifest" and edit it in the 7-Zip archive window itself. There's a tag  as mentioned below along with the tags for VisualStudio versions.
You just need to add the VisualStudio Verion to it that you are using.

```
<SupportedProducts>
  <VisualStudio Version="10.0">
    <Edition>VST_All</Edition>
    <Edition>Pro</Edition>
  </VisualStudio>
  <VisualStudio Version="11.0">
    <Edition>VST_All</Edition>
    <Edition>Pro</Edition>
  </VisualStudio>
<VisualStudio Version="12.0">
     <Edition>VST_All</Edition>
     <Edition>Pro</Edition>
  </VisualStudio>
</SupportedProducts>
```

Like I added  the following to the "extension.vsixmanifest" file.

```
</VisualStudio>
<VisualStudio Version="12.0">
     <Edition>VST_All</Edition>
     <Edition>Pro</Edition>
  </VisualStudio>
```

Next, as I stated earlier, you should be able to install the extension simply by double-clicking on it. But if that doesn't works out, try this:

**Run 'Developer Command Prompt for VS2013' as Administrator
and use the VSIXInstaller tool to install the extension by running the following command:**

> VSIXInstaller "path_to_VSIX_file"

Now pack the contents back into a zip-archive. Make sure the archive have the VSIX extension.
And as shown in the image above, alongwith VS2010, VS2013 would also be shown for installing this extension to.

Hope this helps.